# Django: cannot import name

Tags: django, import, corruption

I've just encountered a very annoying problem while deploying new updates to my website. I have two seperate websites whereas one of them is a development version. Now when I want to apply my changes to the production it won't work because of error message:

> File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 99, in get_response
>   request.path_info)
>
> File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py",
>   line 249, in resolve    for pattern in
>   self.url_patterns:
>
> File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py",
>   line 278, in _get_url_patterns
>   patterns =
>   getattr(self.urlconf_module,
>   "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
>
> File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py",
>   line 273, in _get_urlconf_module
>   self._urlconf_module =
>   import_module(self.urlconf_name)
>
> File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py",
>   line 35, in import_module
>   **import**(name)
>
> File
>   "/srv/websites/spelutveckla_se/urls.py",
>   line 21, in 
>   (r'^account/login/$',
>   LoginView.as_view()),
>
> NameError: name 'LoginView' is not
>   defined

It doesn't matter if I remove that app, view, class or module because it will complain about an other module instead. LoginView IS defined in an import statement. The files are just a fresh copy of the development files (except for settings.py) that is running on an another subdomain without any problem. I've checked the settings.py several times and made sure the correct settings are set (differs by a couple of directory paths). I've also checked that the apache2 www-data user has permission to access the files. i've also restarted apache a couple of times and re-copied the files over and over but nothing works.

I'm desperate and have no clue of what the problem might be...?

Here's what my urls.py looks like at the top:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView, TemplateView
from django.contrib import admin
from project.models import Project
from project.views import Detail, EditView as EditProject, CreateProjectView, EditProjectLinksView, EditProjectFeedsView, EditProjectTagsView, EditMultimediaView, PostForumTopic, AudioFormset
from frontpage.views import FrontpageView
from userprofile.views import UserRegistrationView, UserRegistrationActivationView, LogoutView, UserProfileView, LoginView, EditProfileView, CreateUserProfileView
from registration.views import activate as UserActivatedView
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You most likely had a circular import in the module `LoginView` was defined in, i.e. when you were importing the `views` module that defined `LoginView`, some statement somehow in turn imported some other module that was still waiting to get fully interpreted.

Here's an example to give you a better idea:

```
# myapp.urls

from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from myapp import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ...
)

# myapp.views

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

class SomeCreateView(CreateView):

    # BOOM!
    success_url = reverse('myapp:some-url')
```

Once `myapp.views` gets imported and the `SomeCreateView` type gets allocated to memory, `reverse('myapp:some-url')` will get executed and your `myapp.urls` will eventually be imported by Django, only that that won't ever be possible since `myapp.urls` will indefinitely wait for `myapp.views` to get imported.

Comment: I have similar problem with Staging and Production env. On staging when first run I get ```Error: cannot import name Cart```. Then after a few page refreshes everything starts to work.

Nothing like that happens on production.

Still the problem is that I can't run ./manage.py command on staging as it's constantly gives me an error.

Comment: try deleting all the pyc file

Comment: Thank you, you pointed out the exact case I had. A `reverse` url defined as a class variable in my models. I was hunting for circular imports, not other weird cases like this. Just saved me a lot of hair pulling.