# cannot import LoginView?

Tags: django, django-1.9

i'm learning some things about Django 1.9 and i want to make a login form but with class-based views.

This is mi view code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

class AlumnoLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = "alumno/login.html"
    redirect_authenticated_user = True
```

And this is my urls code:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from .views import AlumnoLoginView

app_name = 'alumno'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', AlumnoLoginView.as_view(), name="login"),
]
```

This make an error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name LoginView
```

But if I delete the code inside urls nothing happens.

This is the full error trace (with François change):

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f044ad8ac08>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/plafhz/Envs/StudentAdmin/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/plafhz/Envs/StudentAdmin/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/plafhz/Envs/StudentAdmin/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/plafhz/Envs/StudentAdmin/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/plafhz/Envs/StudentAdmin/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/plafhz/Envs/StudentAdmin/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/home/plafhz/Envs/StudentAdmin/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/plafhz/Envs/StudentAdmin/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/plafhz/Envs/StudentAdmin/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/plafhz/Envs/StudentAdmin/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/plafhz/Envs/StudentAdmin/studentadmin/studentadmin/urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    url(r'^alumno/', include('alumno.urls')),
  File "/home/plafhz/Envs/StudentAdmin/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 52, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/plafhz/Envs/StudentAdmin/studentadmin/alumno/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from alumno.views import AlumnoLoginView
  File "/home/plafhz/Envs/StudentAdmin/studentadmin/alumno/views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView as BaseLoginView
ImportError: cannot import name LoginView
```

What is wrong?
How I fix it?
Thank :)

Comment: Do you use / import the original LoginView in your urls or somewhere else? Try with `from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView as BaseLoginView`

Comment: Also, can you paste the full error trace?

Comment: I read something similar [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238658/django-cannot-import-name) about circular import but i don't understand how to fix it@ François

Comment: @Darshit answer is correct ! plafhz where did you find LoginView?

Comment: https://github.com/django/django/blob/255fb992845e987ef36e3d721a77747a0b2df620/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L358 and also here https://github.com/django/django/blob/255fb992845e987ef36e3d721a77747a0b2df620/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L56

Answer (score 3):

Class-based views [LoginView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView) and LogoutView are introduced on Django 1.11 and function-based views 'login' and 'logout' are [deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.11/#id2) since then.

You can use class-based views LoginView and LogoutView like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view(template_name='...'), name="login"),

]
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no view called LoginView in django.contrib.auth.views
I think you need.

from django.contrib.auth.views import login

Comment: LoginView is only in the `dev` release of Django as of August 2015 -- it is not available in 1.9 or 1.10.0.

Answer (score 0):

LoginView only available from Django 1.11

Answer (score 0):

cannot import LoginView? 
You must be using lower version of django ..Login view supported only in 1.11 or higher version.. 
You need to install 1.11 or higher version

pip install django==1.11